# How to append a hidden submit input in children props (React)

Tags: reactjs

I have a common modal with a footer submit button. The modal is able to accept children.

```
const Modal = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<Props>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      <div>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

Usage

```
const CreateModal = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <Modal>
      <form>
        <input name="test" />
      </form>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default CreateModal
```

Currently, that are a lot of files using the Modal component and I don't want to move the form tag in the modal.

My question is how can I modify the children in the common modal component? I want to append a hidden input inside the form so that I can submit the form when press Enter.

Wonder if using react cloneElement is able to solve my problem as I know it only can pass additional props to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using react hook form btw.
This is how I solve it.

```
    <ModalBody display="flex" flexDirection="column">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {children}
        <input hidden type="submit" />
      </form>
    </ModalBody>
```

I still need to edit all files but for future usage, I no need to include a hidden input for all files.

The only thing I worry is the FormProvider now is nested inside the form. By default the `<FormProvider>` should be the parent of the `<form>`.